# Is there a color standard for painted toroidal magnetic cores?

Tags: magnetics, ferrite

Is there a color standard for painted toroidal magnetic cores ?

I noticed that yellow-white usually means a powdered iron core with a relative permeability of around 100 at frequencies below 10kHz.

What do the other colors mean ?

[image]

Comment: I think I've found two or three standards, some of which conflict (in my opinion) But I'm a hobbyist, so I'll be looking for the really good answers from the really good engineers here and learn from it. +1 My practice is, if repurposing cores, to test them either near my frequency of interest or else several "interesting" frequencies when storing them. I'm annoyed at myself for not having a good answer. So thanks for asking this.

Answer (score 1):

Colours are not an industry standard for ferrites as these recipes are proprietary and there are many variations of different materials.

You might want to contact the supplier for specs and if none, continue with your trial and error methods.  The most important aspect is often the power losses at certain temperature ranges in order to be thermally stable.

This major MAGNETICS company (by same name) simplifies their specs down to 4 different materials P,F,R,K

http://c1233384.r84.cf3.rackcdn.com/UK_MAG_ferrite_material_selection_guide_AN.pdf
[image]

I do have several books of hundreds of different ferrite samples from TDK, if anyone is interested in paying for shipping  them.

Answer (score 0):

Color codes depend on materials. as an example, for an iron powder toroidal core with yellow-white CC:

Material=#26, Perm=75, T.Stab.=882ppm/deg.C, freq range=LF applications

Other colors are tan, blue,red,etc. Manufacturers' web sites cover data, but slight variations may exist.